Getting public key for validating JWT
I am getting a JWT from login.microsoftonline.com and I need to get its public key to validate it. I am using PyJWKClient to get it, thusly:
import jwt
import certifi
import ssl
from jwt import PyJWKClient

token = "my JWT" 
url = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/discovery/v2.0/keys"
JWT_AUDIENCE = "my audience"
JWT_ISSUER = "my issuer"

ssl_context = ssl.create_default_context(cafile=certifi.where())
jwks_client = PyJWKClient(url, ssl_context=ssl_context)

signing_key = jwks_client.get_signing_key_from_jwt(token)

data = jwt.decode(
    token,
    signing_key.key,
    algorithms=["RS256"],
    audience=JWT_AUDIENCE,
    issuer=JWT_ISSUER
)

This fails with jwt.exceptions.InvalidSignatureError: Signature verification failed
I have verified the audience and issuer match what is in the JWT and that what is returned from https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/discovery/v2.0/keys contains the kid in the JWT, and the JWT is not expired. What am I doing wrong here?
